# IONIC 5 / Angular 9 lazy load specific components in native builds

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework, lazy-loading

In my App, some Components only required by specific user groups. Too keep the download size small I want to load some of these components after the login and save them local in the native Apps (IOS, Android, Electron).

I already know that I can lazy load modules, but this is only working at the Web / PWA version.

Comment: It would be useful if you could post your code of what you have tried so far.

Comment: So you are saying that don't want to even _ship_ the components? I believe this is technically possible, but the complexity and maintenance cost is unbelievably high.